# How to create a user in the Moodle Rest WS using the Python Requests module?

Tags: python, web-services, rest, python-requests, moodle

I'm trying to create a user using the Moodle Webservices - Rest Server, but I'm stuck at the validation of the params :S My code is the following:

```
import requests

token = 'TOKENNUMBER'
function = 'core_user_create_users'


url = 'http://localhost/webservice/rest/server.php?wstoken={0}&wsfunction={1}&moodlewsformat=json'.format(token,function)

user1 = {'email': 'email@local.host','firstname': 'firstname',
'lastname': 'lastname', 'createpassword': 1,
'username': 'username'}
```

Then, I try to post the data (two different ways):

```
requests.post(url,data={'users': user1})
requests.post(url,data={'users': [user1,]})
```

And moodle keeping return the error:

```
Only arrays accepted. The bad value is: \'username\'</DEBUGINFO>
```

In the documentation (available from the own moodle), its stated:

```
Argumentos
users (Obrigatório)


Estrutura geral

list of ( 
object {
username string   //Username policy is defined in Moodle security config.
password string  Opcional //Plain text password consisting of any characters
createpassword int  Opcional //True if password should be created and mailed to user.
firstname string   //The first name(s) of the user
lastname string   //The family name of the user
email string   //A valid and unique email address
auth string  Padrão para "manual" //Auth plugins include manual, ldap, imap, etc
idnumber string  Padrão para "" //An arbitrary ID code number perhaps from the institution
lang string  Padrão para "pt_br" //Language code such as "en", must exist on server
calendartype string  Padrão para "gregorian" //Calendar type such as "gregorian", must exist on server
theme string  Opcional //Theme name such as "standard", must exist on server
timezone string  Opcional //Timezone code such as Australia/Perth, or 99 for default
mailformat int  Opcional //Mail format code is 0 for plain text, 1 for HTML etc
description string  Opcional //User profile description, no HTML
city string  Opcional //Home city of the user
country string  Opcional //Home country code of the user, such as AU or CZ
firstnamephonetic string  Opcional //The first name(s) phonetically of the user
lastnamephonetic string  Opcional //The family name phonetically of the user
middlename string  Opcional //The middle name of the user
alternatename string  Opcional //The alternate name of the user
preferences  Opcional //User preferences
list of ( 
object {
type string   //The name of the preference
value string   //The value of the preference
} 
)customfields  Opcional //User custom fields (also known as user profil fields)
list of ( 
object {
type string   //The name of the custom field
value string   //The value of the custom field
} 
)} 
)
```

So, with this in mind, how can I create a Moodle user using python requests module? Whats wrong with the data that has been passed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use REST service in Moodle, parameters to function has to be formated in a flat dictionary. The structure of the arguments reflects in names of the keys. In your example, you have one argument *courses* which is a list. So keys of your dictionary will be *courses[0]email*, *courses[0]firstname*, ... for the first user, and  *courses[1]email*, *courses[1]firstname*, ... for the second and so on

```
users = {'users[0]email': 'email@local.host',
         'users[0]firstname': 'firstname',
         'users[0]lastname': 'lastname', 
         'users[0]createpassword': 1,
         'users[0]username': 'username'}
requests.post(url,data=users)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. To me, the format is really very weird ... Seems they are using array column or something like that to get the index ...

Comment: it seems that in newer Moodle versions it has changed a bit. What worked for me was something like ```{'users[0][email]': 'email@local.host' , ...}``` , adding brackets to the key.